# How do I access this information in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I can't access the information in this object

[image: screenshot]

The ts file

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 
         'angularfire2/database'
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title:AngularFireObject<any>;
 message: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){
     this.title = db.object('message');
     this.message = this.title.valueChanges();
    }

 }
```

and the html file:

```
<p> {{message | async | json}} </p>
```

But I got this in my HTML Page:

```
{
    "-LKbddlCLBERGd6y4MD2": {
        "email": "rakiubl97@gmail.com",
        "message": "sa",
        "timeStand": "2018/8/23 16:38:12",
        "username": "Rakibul"
    },
    ... this repeats a similar object many times
}
```

I want to access them one by one. Whatever I like to access.

Comment: Have you code something?

Comment: I added the photo. Please check now

Comment: You've added a photo of the Firebase data, not what you have try already

Comment: I added the code also. Please check

Comment: Hi @Moumitaakter! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify what you're asking for in your question. Are you asking for how to access all of the data in your database in the `messages` property, or are you asking for how to access only an individual property in your `messages` property?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the properties of the object using the `for-in` loop. You can push the contents of the object into an array and then run `*ngFor` over that array to access any property.

```
for (var key in message){
  console.log('Email: ', message[key].email);    

  // push message[key] into an array
  messages.push(message[key]);
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<p *ngFor="let m of messages"> {{m.email}} </p>
```

---

**Running code snippet:-**

```js
var message = {
  'lkdp': {
    email: 'email 1'
  },
  'lkdq': {
    email: 'email 2'
  },
}

for (var key in message){
  console.log('Email: ', message[key].email);
}
```

Comment: Thaks Ankit but Its only access the local object. I want to access the database object.

Comment: @Moumitaakter - Then you need to make an API call. I thought you have this data present at the front end side already

Comment: Yes I have the data

Comment: @Moumitaakter - Then whats the problem. The above solution should work just fine for you, is it not? Ofcourse you will have to convert `message` to `this.message` in case that is a class property. Also, you can always convert the `var` keyword to `const`.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Please clarify what you're asking for in your question. Are you asking on how to access all of the data at once? Or, are you asking on how to access only one property? The solution below is answering the former question (AKA *How do I access all of the data in the `messages` property at once?*).

---

That's because you're using the `AngularFireDatabase#object` method which only returns an object.

What you're looking for is the `AngularFireDatabase#list` method:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: AngularFireObject<any>;
  message: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){
    this.title = db.list('message');
    this.message = this.title.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Edric.
I'm new in StackOverflow. And it's my very first question.
I'm asking on how I access a single piece of data in the messages property?
I already figure it our how to access the whole message property data at once.

Comment: @Moumitaakter Sorry to ask, but are you only accessing one _specific_ item, or do you want to access a random item from the property?